# Hive tez query fails with java.io.IOException

Tags: hadoop, hive, apache-tez

Executing a long running Hive Tez query, it rarely fails with:

```
java.io.IOException: File hdfs://XXX with newer attempt ID 1 is smaller than the file hdfs://YYY with older attempt ID 0
```

In our 20 node HDP 3.1.5 cluster (Hive 3.1.0 and Tez 0.9.1), it fails once over around 200 executions

Answer (score 0):

We where hitting [HIVE-23354](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-23354)

It seems to have no workaround. It is solved at Hive 4.0.0

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with a query with lots of big joins. Decresing (512 mb->16 mb in my case) the size of the tables that fit in memory, namely `hive.auto.convert.join.noconditionaltask.size` solved the problem for me.

Stack: HDP 3.1.4, Tez 0.9.1, Hive 3.1.0.